# Flask application in spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I am trying to run a simple flask application in spyder(anaconda). But I am not getting expected results. Can anyone help me here?

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


def return_val(a):
    return a+1

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return return_val(8)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=8080)
```

I am expecting 9 to be printed on the application.

Comment: What is the error message? Change the port (8080 is common) to see if it helps. Ensure the new port is open on your windows firewall.

Comment: Error is "Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application."

Comment: i tried but did not work. The code is right? I am guessing there might issue with the code